# How can I dynamically Add css property to div class using javascript when converting to pdf using rotativa?

Tags: javascript, rotativa

```
<div id="mainDiv" class="watermark" style="font-family: Calibri; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid lightgrey;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                var watermarkImage = "url(../../Resources/Watermark/" + @Model.Watermark + ".png)";
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("watermark");

                x.setAttribute('background-image', watermarkImage);
                x.setAttribute('background-repeat', 'repeat-y')
            })();
        </script>
```

I am using mvc + rotativa to convert cshtml to pdf. I have passed Image name from controller. But when pdf is generated watermark is not coming. I want to add css property to div class using javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) + `x.style.backgroundImage = ...;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add CSS to a single block having unique id then Try Below Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                var watermarkImage = "url(../../Resources/Watermark/" + @Model.Watermark + ".png)";
               document.getElementById("mainDiv").style.background-image = watermarkImage;
               document.getElementById("mainDiv").style.background-repeat = 'repeat-y';
             })();
</script>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: No: `.style.background-image`, and no: `.style.'background-repeat`

Comment: Then What is the needs?

Comment: The properties are `backgroundImage` and `backgroundRepeat`

Comment: The thing is if I add css properties to div, it wont work.

Comment: I want to add css properties to class named "watermark"

Comment: please read [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) carefully. Applying style like : element.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;"); is bad way to do it.

Comment: Thanks mate. Its really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
 x.style.background-image= watermarkImage;
 x.style.background-repeat =  repeat-y;
```

For more information you can use this link 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: Yes, I got the solution
`var x = document.getElementsByClassName("watermark");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.backgroundImage = watermarkImage;
      x[i].style.backgroundRepeat = 'repeat-y';
                }`

Comment: But it only works for static url. Its not working for dynamic url from controller

Answer (score 0):

When using rotativa to generate pdf, "@" symbol depricated the rest of the code when it is used in `<script>` tag and `<style>` tag. So we cant set background-image url in variable or cannot pass from controller. I solved by following way

```
@if (Model.IsArchieved == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ArchivedVersion))
{
    <style type="text/css">
        .watermark {
            background-image: url(../../Resources/Watermark/Archived.png);
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-size: 600px 300px;
        }
    </style>
}
@if (Model.IsPublished == false)
{
    <style type="text/css">
        .watermark {
            background-image: url(../../Resources/Watermark/Draft5.png);
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-size: 500px 275px;
        }
    </style>
}
```